# WPF - RangeSlider wont display only integers

Tags: c#, wpf, rangeslider

I am working on a project where I need to have prices. So I used a RangeSlider from the [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RangeSlider&referringTitle=Home) to select price range.

I also made 2 textblocks that display the lower and the higher value. But the problem is that it displays only numbers with decimals. I want integers.

```
<wpfTool:RangeSlider Name="rangeSlider" Grid.Row="4" LowerValue="300" Minimum="300" Maximum="2300" HigherValue="2300" LowerValueChanged="RangeSlider_LowerValueChanged"/>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,26.983,0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LowerValue, ElementName=rangeSlider, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <TextBlock Width="50"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HigherValue, ElementName=rangeSlider, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="44"/>
            <TextBlock Text="€" Width="11"/>
        </WrapPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RangeSlider has 2 Slider controls in its template. You can make Slider to select only integers. The relevant property is `IsSnapToTickEnabled`. To change that property for nested Sliders add a style into RangeSlider Resources:

```
<wpfTool:RangeSlider Name="rangeSlider" Grid.Row="4" 
                     LowerValue="300" Minimum="300" Maximum="2300" HigherValue="2300" 
                     LowerValueChanged="RangeSlider_LowerValueChanged"/>
    <wpfTool:RangeSlider.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Slider">
            <Setter Property="IsSnapToTickEnabled" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </wpfTool:RangeSlider.Resources>
</wpfTool:RangeSlider>
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need a converter, like this...

```
internal class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is double)
        {
            return ((double)value).ToString("f0");
        }
        return "";
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Declared in XAML like this...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And referenced in XAML like this...

```
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding HigherValue, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ElementName=rangeSlider, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="44"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm kinda new to WPF and C#, so how do I implement this in XAML? It says that the name "MyConverter"  doesn't exist in the namespace.